# LNK2019 - unresolved external symbol error

Tags: c++, linker, lnk2019

I have a problem when compiling my main class.

```
//main.cpp    
#include "Division.h"

int main() {
    Division Root;
}
```

Here is my Division.h

```
//Division.h
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

class Division {
public:
    Division();
    Division(std::string Name, std::string PhoneNumber, std::string Description, Division& Parent);
private:
    UUID GUID;
    std::string Name;
    std::string PhoneNumber;
    std::string Description;
    Division* Parent;
};
```

And here is my Division.cpp

```
#include <string>                                                                           
#include <windows.h>                                                                            

using namespace std;                                                                            

class Division {
public:
    Division() {};

    Division(string Name, string PhoneNumber, string Description, Division &Parent) {       
        UuidCreate(&GUID);                                                                  
        this->Name = Name;
        this->PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
        this->Description = Description;
        this->Parent = &Parent;
    }
    

private:
    UUID GUID;                                                                              
    string Name;
    string PhoneNumber;
    string Description;
    Division* Parent;
};
```

In the main class I just want to create an empty Division object using the first constructor.
Why am I getting the Linker error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: None of this is C. Tagging C in this situation will only attract C experts which then will actively look for reasons to close, delete or downvote your question.

Comment: Please provide more debugging details, [mre], full textual quote of all errors, ....

Answer (score 2):

You have declared Division twice, both in header and cpp file.

You should only have the declaration in the header.

In the .cpp file include the header and define the methods

```
Division::Division() {}

Division::Division(std::string name, std::string phoneNumber, std::string description, Division &parent) {       
  UuidCreate(&GUID);                                                                  
  Name = name;
  PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
  Description = description;
  Parent = &parent;
}
```

It is also good to use other names for member variables than parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I did as you said, but now I'm getting another unresolved external symbol error concerning the &GUID variable. If I comment out the UuidCreate line, it works fine.

Comment: @Vento Are you sure it's the variable it's complaining about and not the `UuidCreate` function? Did you link with the `Rpcrt4` library? I see that you don't `#include <Rpc.h>` which should should.

Comment: I included the windows.h library in my header, which contains Rpcrt4. I tried to replace windows.h with Rpc.h, as you suggested, but the error remains the same.

Comment: Link with Rpcrt4.lib and add include rpcdce.h. Windows.h does not contain Rpcrt4 (what do you mean by this?)

Comment: @Vento https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/rpcdce/nf-rpcdce-uuidcreate just add header and lib as S.M. said and you should be fine, but check return value from function too.